# GAE(python): set Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, http, google-app-engine

I have a static page in google app engine(python), and I want to $.load() the content of this page from another page -> therefore I have a CORS problem. How can I set in GAE to allow all domains to load the content of the page?(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)

Answer (score 6):

In app.yaml

```
http_headers:
  X-Foo-Header: foo
  X-Bar-Header: bar value
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using webapp (you haven't specified), put this anywhere in your handler:

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

Comment: I have written, that I use a static page

Comment: @Le_Coeur Sorry, I missed that. In that case, you'll have to convert it to a dynamic page, unless a meta tag will work (which I doubt).